# Kill a background process using command

Tags: python, shell, unix, kill

I am trying to kill a process which I ran in back ground not I want to cancel it using a command line. Below is the command I am using but I am getting error "Operation not permitted".

```
ps -aef | grep gs_roach | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -2
```

Comment: the process might be running under super-user such as root.

Answer (score -1):

At first, 2 is SIGINT. SIGINT is the interrupt signal. The terminal sends it to the foreground process when the user presses ctrl-c.

Secondly, you do now own the process you are trying to kill. This is the reason for both ps output —which did not list process — and the sudo requirement to kill the process.

You can use ps -aux to list all processes including those you don't own. You can also use -p argument to show a specific process which best fit your need

If you need to kill a process;
try kill command with with -9 signal

if the following command does not work

```
sudo kill PROCESS_ID
```

try to use the following command:

```
sudo kill -9 PROCESS_ID
```

or try to use the following command:

```
sudo kill -s SIGKILL PROCESS_ID
```

--

### Please vote my answer, if my solution help you. Because I need to unlock my account! Thanks!

Comment: `kill  -9` should be the last resort. Try `kill -15 $pid` first. Good luck to all.